# Capturing Audio through Linux in J2ME WTK Emulator

Tags: linux, java-me, emulation, audio-recording, java-wireless-toolkit

Is it possible to capture audio in the J2ME WTK emulator on a Linux platform? Has anyone on this forum succeeded in doing so?

Comment: Which J2ME program do you think produces audio worth capturing?

Comment: Oh, you want to record audio from the user's microphone into a file.

Answer (score 1):

No so far..Hopefuly in next versions of WTK.